# Why other people except myself cant see my auto blog post on my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, publish

ugin and facebook application id and secrete key I can austomatically post my blog post into my facebook business page. But the problem is only I can see the post but other people cant see that post. But if I post anything directly from my facebook account into that page other people can see that. How could I make visible my auto post via facebook app into facebook ? Please help

Comment: I'm not even sure that this is a programming question. Even if it is there's nothing here that would allow us to help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Status & Review" in your App settings and check out that box next to the following text: "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" - make sure it is set to "YES".